# Python: Find a list of words in a text and return its index

Tags: python, text, cpu-word, nltk

I have to process a document in plain text, looking for a word list and returning a text window around each word found. I'm using [NLTK](http://nltk.org/).

I found posts on Stack Overflow where they use regular expressions for finding words, but without getting their index, just printing them. I don't think use RE is right, cause I have to find specific words.

Comment: You should use regular expressions..

Comment: > I don't think use RE is right, cause I have to find specific words. You don't have to find specific words using regular expressions.... and usually you can find anything that you're looking for using regular expressions when parsing text. You should just stick with using regular expressions. And also, please post an example of the actual code you're trying to make, or the kind of thing you want to be able to find in the text you're searching. And what have you tried?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start

Comment: Sorry that was not clear, it is my first message. I found a word with str.find, and then getting the window easily. But I have many words, that can be repeated. So, once I find the first occurrence of a word, how I can find the second without modifying the text?

Comment: Well you could capture it as a group and set a variable to that and then search for that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

- You can either use str.index or str.find:

Contents of file:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sollicitudin tortor et velit venenatis molestie. Morbi non nibh magna, quis tempor metus. 
Vivamus vehicula velit sit amet neque posuere id hendrerit sem venenatis. Nam vitae felis sem. Mauris ultricies congue mi, eu ornare massa convallis nec. 
Donec volutpat molestie velit, scelerisque porttitor dui suscipit vel. Etiam feugiat feugiat nisl, vitae commodo ligula tristique nec. Fusce bibendum fermentum rutrum.

>>>a = open("file.txt").read()

>>>print a.index("vitae")
232
>>> print a.find("vitae")
232
```

## --Edit--

Ok, if you have same words in multiple indices try using a generator,

```
def all_occurences(file, str):
    initial = 0
    while True:
        initial = file.find(str, initial)
        if initial == -1: return
        yield initial
        initial += len(str)


>>>print list(all_occurences(open("file.txt").read(),"vitae"))
[232, 408]
```

Comment: How would find the second occurrence of vitae?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, building a positional index is what you want

```
from collections import defaultdict

text = "your text goes here"
pos_index = defaultdict(list)
for pos, term in enumerate(text.split()):
    pos_index[term].append(pos)
```

Now you have an index with each word's positions. Just query it by term..

Comment: Thank you. I will study this possibility, but I try to find a few words in a text. I may not have explained well, I could do a dictionary as you do but with occurrences of certain words in a text, rather than for all the words of the text.

Answer (score 1):

try this, where `log` is the txt and `word_search` is the term you are trying to index in `log`

```
 [i for i, item in enumerate(log) if item == word_search]
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its been a while since you've asked the question, but since you're already using nltk I would sugest you to use its tool word_tokenize:

```
text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.'
for index, word in enumerate(nltk.word_tokenize(text)):
  print(index, word)
```

The result would be:

0 Lorem
1 ipsum
2 dolor
3 sit
4 amet
5 ,
6 consectetur
7 adipiscing
8 elit
9 .

Hope it helps :)